# Gegenstück von "digital" – "physisch" oder "physikalisch"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage, technical-terminology

Ich möchte ausdrücken, dass ein Dokument sowohl auf dem Computer als auch auf Papier vorliegt. "Auf dem Computer" kürze ich zu *digital* ab; ist die korrekte Entsprechung für "auf Papier" dann *physikalisch* oder *physisch*? Ich meine, *physikalisch* müsste stimmen, bin mir aber nicht ganz sicher.

Comment: Physisch: körperlich, gegenständlich. Physikalisch: der Physik folgend. Daher ist **physisch** korrekt, denn das Dokument liegt sowohl digital als auch als Gegenstand (Papier) vor.

Comment: I am not sure whether this will help you, but in English, the distinctions are: 'virtual' vs 'real' or 'physical' 'digital' vs 'analogue'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Das "Standard"-Gegenteil ist eigentlich

> analog

Im gegebenen Kontext würde ich entweder das Papier anfügen oder gleich nur mit Papier arbeiten

> sowohl digital als auch analog, sprich auf Papier...
>
> sowohl digital als auch in Papierform...

Comment: Wäre physikalisch denn tatsächlich **falsch** oder nur unüblich? Ich brauche ähnliche Formulierungen auch noch in Bezug auf andere Dinge, die sowohl digital als auch [analog/pyhsikalisch/physisch] vorliegen, bei denen das mit dem Papier dann nicht funktioniert ...

Comment: @Gin-San... ne, falsch nicht. Nur unüblich. Aber wenn, dann "physikalisch". "Physisch" geht, zumindest für mein Empfinden sehr um den menschlichen Körper. Hast du Beispiele für die anderen Kontexte?

Comment: Habe vorhin von "digitalen und physikalischen Ordnern" gesprochen, also Computerordner vs. gute, altmodische Pappordner. Oder auch Spiele, die digital oder auf physikalischen/analogen Datenträgern vorliegen können

Comment: Gerade bei den Ordnern hätte ich jetzt eher "physikalisch" geschrieben, "analog" klingt für mich so auf Datensätze, Texte u.a. bezogen anstatt auf die tatsächlichen physikalischen Eigenschaften von anfassbaren Dingen ... macht das noch Sinn? :D

Comment: "Papierform" ist hier im Kontext gängig. "Physikalisch" klingt für die meisten Leute bescheuert, wenn sie überhaupt verstehen was gemeint ist.

Comment: Schrift auf Papier ist immer noch digital, v.a. gedrucktes - siehe auch meine Antwort.

Comment: @userunknown.... wenn man streng nach Definitionen geht, dann vielleicht, aber im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch nicht. Davon abgesehen... ist nicht, wenn man die Quantentheorie verwendet, so ziemlich alles digital?

Comment: @Emanuel: In der Quantenphysik ja, aber da sich kaum jmd. Quantenphysikalisch mit Mails befasst kann das hier nicht gemeint sein. Analog heißt "stufenlos". Wie liegt ein Text stufenlos vor? Allenfalls als Handschrift (aber nicht gedruckt in Handschriftfont). Eine gescannte Handschrift wiederum wäre sowohl analog als auch digital. Also was soll eigentlich ausgedrückt werden? Wenn die Begriffe das nicht deutlich machen sind sie untauglich, auch wenn sie gängig sind.

Comment: @userunknown... das bin ich anderer Meinung. Begriffe sind immer dann tauglich, wenn sie den kommunikativen Zweck erfüllen. Das ein Begriff nicht für alle exakt gleich konnotiert ist, ist klar. Für mich ist ein "teures Essen" was anderes, als für einen im Penthaus auf Alt Stralau. Aber wenn ich frage "Hast du das Buch analog oder digital?" wird mich jeder verstehen. Auch du. Die Sprache hat ihren Zweck erfüllt. Mehr muss sie nicht. Präzise sein muss sie nur in der Wissenchaft und der Juristerei... wobei zweiteres seine ganz eigene Art von "präzise" hat.

Comment: Ich sehe da einen Unterschied, ob man jmd. verstehen will oder ob man sich verständlich machen will. Für ersteres hat man einen Kontext, aus dem man schließen kann und wird die wahrscheinlichste Bedeutung wählen. Will man sich aber selbst ausdrücken, so sollte man sich um Klarheit bemühen und kann schlecht generelle Empfehlungen geben, die letztlich schlecht sind. "Dokument" ist nicht gleich Buch. Ein Digitalfoto ist auch ein Dokument oder eine wav-Datei. Auf dem USB-Stick ist für mich nicht auf dem Computer aber ebenfalls digital. Eine gescannte Handschrift ist auch analog.

Comment: @userunknown... dann sieh "digital" doch einfach als Metapher für etwas auf dem Computer und "analog" als Metapher für das Gegenteil. Im Übrigen gehört zu einem gelungenen KOmmunikationsakt immer beides... die Absicht zu verstehen und die Absicht verstanden zu werden. Ist ja richtig, was du sagst darüber was "digital" EIGENTLICH heißt. Aber in der Praxis interessiert das keinen.

Comment: Noch was... könnte der Downvoter bitte erklären wo das Problem ist? Die Frage war, wie etwas ausgedrückt werden soll, und die habe ich so beantwortet, dass man mit der Antwort in die freie Wildbahn gehen kann. Ein Downvote ist nur dann angebracht wenn die Antwort FALSCH ist, sprich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch NICHT zum erwünschten Kommunikationsergebnis führt. Wer das denkt, bitte begründen, eine bessere Alternative vorschlagen und Quellen nennen. Danke

Comment: a) Du brauchst mir keine Tipps geben wie ich die Sprache verstehen soll - gefragt war, wie etwas geeignet ausgedrückt wird, und da interessieren mich mediokre Lösungen nicht. b) Bin ich kein Niemand, der nicht zählt bei der Frage wie es richtig heißt. Der Fragesteller vor allem kommt dazu. Auf einer Sprachseite Werbung für schlechte Sprache zu machen kann ich Dir aber nicht verbieten. c) Der Tooltiptext sagt "answer not useful", nicht "answer wrong". Vielleicht soll ich das auch als Metapher verstehen? Kann ein Adjektiv überhaupt eine Metapher sein? Ich würde sagen nein.

Answer (score 9):

Hier noch die Antwort zur Frage nach dem Unterschied zwischen [physisch](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=physisch) und [physikalisch](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=physikalisch). Beide kann man nach Englisch mit *[physical](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=physical&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)* übersetzen, jedoch ist die Bedeutung im Deutschen unterschiedlich:

> [**physisch:**](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=physisch)
>   *körperlich, materiell, stofflich, die Physis betreffend*
>   [**physikalisch:**](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=physikalisch)
>   *den Gesetzen der Physik folgend, die Gesetze der Physik betreffend, bestimmt durch Gesetze der Physik*

Somit passt im erwähnten Zusammenhang allenfalls **physisch** in der Bedeutung von *stofflich, materiell*. Auch die digitale Datenspeicherung folgt physikalischen Gesetzen und wäre somit "physikalisch".

Comment: Festplatten, USB-Sticks, CDs usw. sind aber auch stofflich/körperlich. Der Gegensatz zu physisch wäre m.E. ideell. Das Ideelle liegt aber im Hirn auch wieder stofflich vor, wie wir heute wissen - der Gegensatz ist eigentlich obsolet.

Comment: @userunknown: da bin ich ganz anderer Meinung. Der Unterschied ist keinesfalls obsolet nur weil viele Leute ihn nicht kennen und die Begriffe falsch verwenden.

Comment: Festplatten, Sticks, CDs sind tatsächlich physische Medien, die Speicherung und das Auslesen erfolgen auf physikalischen Prinzipien. Insbesondere bei Festplatten ist die abgelegte Information aber nicht stofflich/materiell, sondern immateriell in Form von Magnetfeldern (HDD) oder Bitzuständen (USB). Hinzu kommt, dass die Daten in binärschreibweise (0/1 -> digital) abgelegt werden, die ohne entsprechenden Interpreter nicht "decodiert" werden können. Das Schriftstück liegt nicht physisch auf der Festplatte, sondern als digitales Abbild. Das Schriftstück selbst (analog) ist tatsächlich stofflich.

Answer (score 2):

Das Gegenwort zu **digital** ist **analog**.<sup>[1][2]</sup>

*Physikalisch* und *physisch* sind nicht falsch, jedoch zu ungenau, da die digitalen Daten auch physikalisch und physisch vorliegen (z. B. auf der Festplatte).

> Das Dokument liegt sowohl digital als auch analog vor.

Hier sollte auch jeder an Papier denken, denn Steintafeln sind außer Mode. ;)

> Die Ordner liegen sowohl digital als auch analog vor.
>   Die Musikstücke liegen sowohl digital (FLAC) als auch analog (Vinyl) vor.
>   Die Bilder liegen sowohl digital als auch analog vor.
>   …

#### Referenzen

1. [Wiktionary: digital](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/digital)
2. [Wiktionary: analog](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/analog)

Answer (score 2):

Digital kann auch auf Diskette, USB-Stick, CD usw. sein – es muss keineswegs "auf dem Computer" heißen. Die Existenz als magnetische Ladung ist auch sowohl physisch als auch physikalisch, grenzt also mitnichten von "auf Papier" ab.

Wenn man "auf Computer und auf Papier" sagen will, dann soll man es ruhig genau so auch sagen. Will man etwas anderes sagen soll man in sich gehen und überlegen, was man eigentlich sagen will.

Sofern die Buchstaben auf Papier einfach der Ausdruck sind, liegt der Text auf Papier übrigens auch digital vor. Die Buchstaben sind voneinander getrennt.

Womöglich hilft **als Datei** bzw. **gedruckt**.

Comment: Wenn ich das richtig verstehe heißt digital nichts anderes als "in einer Form limitierter Zustände", bzw. "zählbarer" Zustände. Damit ist ein Ausdruck zwar auch digital aber deine Begründung IMO falsch. Der Abstand der Buchstaben spielt für die "Digitalität" keine Rolle

Comment: @Emanuel "Druckbuchstaben haben nämlich eine begrenzte Anzahl an Zuständen." Würde aber ggf. eine klare Definition von Digital als "Zustandsbegrenzt" in der Antwort erfordern

Comment: Man könnte ergänzen, dass Handschrift (aber nicht eine handschriftartige Computerschrift) analog ist insofern, als Druck, Schwung, Buchstabenlänge und -neigung bei jedem Zeichen anders sein kann und sich darüber evtl. Stimmung oder Zustand des Schreibers mitteilen. Mit sehr starker Vergrößerung lässt sich auch bei einem Computerausdruck noch ein Unterschied zw. 2 e finden. Die Frage ist hier was der Kontext sein könnte, in dem die Unterscheidung relevant wird. Im Alltag lässt sich da sicher selten ein Fall finden.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde es auch besser finden, wenn zum Ausdruck gebracht wird, dass das Dokument sowohl zur Weiterbearbeitung als auch zum Anfassen auf Papier vorliegt.

Wenn es dann kurz formuliert sein soll, könnte es vielleicht "sowohl in digitaler als auch gedruckter Form" vorliegen. Physikalisch sind beide Formen.

Comment: Sehr schön! "Gedruckt" ist genau der Ausdruck.

Comment: Gedruckte Schrift ist immer noch digital.

Comment: @userunknown Ob man beim Gedruckten auf die Buchstaben guckt oder auf die Tonerkleckse oder die Abdrücke der Nadel sei dahingestellt. Ich habe in der Einleitung schon zum Ausdruck gebracht, dass ich diese Gegenüberstellung der Formen weniger geeignet finde als die Gegenüberstellung des Verwendungszwecks.

Comment: "Anfassen" scheint mir aber eine seltsame Anforderung, einerseits; andererseits ist die Weiterverarbeitbarkeit bei verschiedenen Dateiformaten auch nicht gegeben, soweit ich weiß. Ob etwas davon ein Kriterium für die Frage war, war auch nicht zu erkennen.

Answer (score 2):

Das eigentliche Problem ist, dass das Wort »digital« hier falsch verwendet wird. »Digital« bedeutet ursprünglich nichts anderes als »in Form von Ziffern«, wobei man im Zusammenhang mit Datenspeicherung auf Computern »Ziffern« als ganze Zahlen zwischen 0 und 255 verstehen kann. Das Wort »digital« kommt vom englischen Wort »digit« für »Ziffer«, und das wiederum vom lateinischen »digitus« für »Finger« (weil man mit den Fingern zählt).

Das was hier eigentlich gemeint ist, ist nicht »digital« sondern »virtuell«. Ein virtuelles Dokument existiert nicht als physischer Gegenstand. Man kann es nicht angreifen, es bekommt keine Flecken wenn man Kaffee darüber gießt, und man kann es nicht abwiegen.

Die Art und Weise wie es gespeichert ist, ist zwar digital, aber das ist nicht worauf es in diesem Zusammenhang ankommt. Eine entsprechende Technologie vorausgesetzt wäre es auch möglich ein Dokument analog, aber trotzdem virtuell abzuspeichern.

Sobald das klar ist, ist auch klar welches Wort man für das Gegenteil verwenden soll:

> digital <-> analog
>   virtuell <-> physisch

Denn »physisch« bedeutet »körperlich«.